# Getting out of the META

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

I noticed that there is not a very straightforward button or tab to click that allows one to leave the meta site and enter the main site and visa versa.

This type of functionality would make using the meta site and main site overall more user friendly and easier if I may say so.

Can this be added?

Comment: You mean other than the "main" link at the top of the page?

Comment: ahh I found it! Why so small?

Comment: The meta is like a blackhole of time and space. Why should you be able to get out??

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I thought that was supposed to be chat...

Comment: @robjohn: I got out of the chat, so it can't be true...

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Since the answer show that such functionality exists, ([tag:support]) might be a more appropriate tag than ([tag:feature-request]).

Answer (score 13):

For future readers:
 [image: Roadmap]

I guess it's that small because the link to get to the meta site is also that small.

Comment: Strangely enough this is the first time I've ever used that link to get here or leave here... I wonder how many others are similar or if I'm the only person too lazy to look around

Comment: @frogeyedpeas How did you get to Meta before?

Comment: I'd click on my name then view my profile then click on main user and then hit the big "MATHEMATICS" title button

Comment: You can also use "chat" and then the "Mathematics" button at the top.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas, anorton was asking how you got to Meta, not how you got to main.

Comment: Click a link on the side if I could find one.